# Motorcycle won't start

Tags: honda, motorcycle, starting

My bike (Honda Hornet 160R) has been resting idly for more than a week. It has both a kick-starter and an electric starter. When I tried to start my bike day a couple of days back, I found the kick-starter to be quite loose. I mean it went down without much resistance. Then I tried the electric starter. I could hear the cranking, but the engine wouldn't wake up. No idea if it's the clutch plates or fuel clogging or open valves. What can be wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This is going to sound like a stupid question on my part, but check to ensure the spark plug is in place. If it is, I'm wondering if a valve is stuck open. It sounds like you're not getting compression.